# Any point in choosing features with ANOVA before doing linear regression?

Tags: regression, anova

It's well known ANOVA and linear regression are [effectively the same analysis](http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/why-anova-and-linear-regression-are-the-same-analysis/).

With that in mind, is there any point at all in using ANOVA to pick features to later fit a linear regression model?

My guess is no: It's like fitting linear regression, choosing the features that work well, and then fittting a linear regression model *again* only with those features.

I see students and candidates often doing this, and keep wondering why, and if there is any value in this approach at all.

Comment: As your link suggests, try replacing 'ANOVA' by 'linear regression' in your question (Anova is a red herring).

Comment: Yes @user603. That's what I was thinking, i.e. there is really no point at all in using linear regression to choose features and then using linear regression again with the hope that one gets a better fit? Is it fair to say that the second fit would most likely be _worse_ (or no better) than the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point at all in doing that- as you mentioned they are both general linear models. However they can provide different insights, for example while linear regression focuses on the significant predictors, Anova output focuses on whether/where the group differences are (with performing adhoc analysis). linear Regression does not provide this.